# LVM restore configured lv to have more blocks then are available in vg

Tags: mount, backup, data-recovery, lvm, restore

I recently had a 2TB disk go down due to, albeit, stupidity on my part. Let's just say I won't be working with live power anywhere near my server again. However, I don't have another disk that size, so when I  added a 1TB disk to the vg I tried to edit the backup file to be able to restore my lv. I was successful in doing this before when the drive was "failing" but was still revivable. Only now the drive is DEAD, so I did a similar process but with a smaller disk. I changed the appropriate values like the UUID, dev_size, and pe_count. As I had said, this worked when the failing drive had just become "unknown". Now that I have actually changed the disk, and with a different sized one, the block size is off. Fsck says that there is 1953485824 blocks assigned to the lv, but the physical drive allocation is only 1953478656 blocks. So, to the question at last, is there a way to change the amount of blocks that are assigned to the lv without formatting? I am hopeful for minimal data loss, as these are my personal files, ie pictures, home movies, and oh so many documents. I greatly appreciate any and all helpful responses.
Thank you,
Noobie T Raccoon

P.S. No I don't have any real backups right now, I was in the process of setting up this server which was built from a garbage pile that was outside, I only had to buy RAM as I could not find it in the pile, and I had to use all the drives I had. I was going to be setting up backups once I could afford some more equipment. Again thank you all for your help and I look forward to working with you.

Update...
I went to check the exact number of blocks that were being reported by initializing the fsck command, which I aborted successfully the **First time**, unfortunately my dyslexia got me again and I said no when asked "Would you like to abort".
Now my screen is vomiting numbers and I'm not sure what I should do. I have taken a short video and put a link to it below if anyone wants to take a look. Thank you all again.

"Video Link removed"

Answer (score 0):

So, short of just remaking the filesystem on the LV which, if you look around, is confusing at best, poorly explained, often results in an "unexpected failure". Well, seems to me that after so many you might start to expect that will happen, even just a little. So, I simply used Testdisk and instead of trying to rebuild the LVM, I went into the /dev/dm-0. There I found all of my files, still intact from what I can tell(still very early into the recovery process so I guess anything could happen). Now I am copying the files to another location. Also to answer my second question, which seems no one wanted to look into either, the text that one could see in the video was the individual blocks being reported to STDout. This is the best solution that I could find and the only person I didn't ask and should have was myself. I figured there was a better solution, when I should have just gone with my instincts. Hope that this can someday help someone else with a similar issue as nowhere online did I find anyone having this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).